# pam_mysql / vsftpd error 'AUTHENTICATION FALURE (FIRST_PASS)'

Tags: mysql, ftp, pam

I setup vsftpd and mysql auth via pam on Debian Squeeze.

Config:

```
auth    required    pam_mysql.so user=server passwd=x host=localhost db=server table=ftp usercolumn=username passwdcolumn=password crypt=2 sqllog=1 logtable=ftp_logs logmsgcolumn=msg logusercolumn=user logpidcolumn=pid loghostcolumn=host logrhostcolumn=rhost logtimecolumn=logtime
account required    pam_mysql.so user=server passwd=x host=localhost db=server table=ftp usercolumn=username passwdcolumn=password crypt=2 sqllog=1 logtable=ftp_logs logmsgcolumn=msg logusercolumn=user logpidcolumn=pid loghostcolumn=host logrhostcolumn=rhost logtimecolumn=logtime
```

Now when I login, everything works (no error!),
but in the ftp_logs table it sais:

1. AUTHENTICATION FALURE (FIRST_PASS)
2. AUTHENTICATION SUCCESS
3. QUERYING SUCCESS

It all happens in the same second  and Im using explicit TLS.

Any idea where the FALURE is coming from?